# Is it possible to automate login to Azure AD B2C using the authorization code flow with PKCE

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, pkce

I am setting up a system which uses the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow with PKCE to connect to Azure AD B2C as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow).

In the first step of the flow the user is makes a call to `https://...b2clogin.com.../authorize?...` where they enter their credentials before the initial token is sent back to the redirect URI defined in the query.

I was wondering if it was possible to send through the user credentials with this initial call so that there is no interactive step - this would allow for automated testing without resorting to browser automation.

Comment: This is possible through a headless browser and a library like [PuppeteerJs](https://pptr.dev/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot automate the flow which is designed to be interactive without browser automation.

If you just want to test credentials, you can use ROPC flow:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=app-reg-ga
But that will throttle if all requests are from the same IP.